# Android: String visibility issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Urdu or Arabic Strings are not fully visible in Text View or Buttons.
for e.g: "چ" this is the Urdu AND Arabic letter, its bottom edge is not visible and its the issue with many letters.

thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem before. Here is a workaround: Add these attributes to your TextView's xml:

```
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
android:lineSpacingExtra="5dip"
```

FYI: This issue is now solved in Android Jelly Bean.